# Selecting a specific visible range After Filtering dataset

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the one specific column(excluding the header) after filtering my dataset. If there are multiple rows after filtering, my selection of range works fine and I am able to copy that column into another sheet. However, if there is only one row after filtering, when I specify the range, it selects all the empty cells along with the non-empty cell and my code is malfunctioning. How do I fix this issue?

I have tried using different range properties but couldn't get the desired outcome

```
'''Finding the Pack Test Category from the filtered 1st column'''
Set RngA = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 1)

''Here the selection of range includes all the empty cells as well!
Set RngA = Range(RngA, RngA.End(xlDown)) 

'''Copy & Pasting in the Forecast Sheet for temporary use'''
RngA.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wbA.ActiveSheet.Range("L1")
```

I expect the range to be selected with only the visible cells having data not the empty cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we start with:

[image]

and filter for age above 45:

[image]

we want to copy filtered column **A** to another sheet:

```
Sub KopyOneKolumn()
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim r3 As Range

    Set r1 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range ' the total visible range
    Set r2 = Intersect(r1.Offset(1, 0), r1) ' clip off the header
    Set r3 = Intersect(r2, Columns(1)) ' pick only column A

    r3.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Paste
End Sub
```

Result in Sheet2:

[image]

**NOTE:**

The key point is that `r1` represents a "copy-able" block of visible cells in the autofilter table.

Comment: I tested the your code..That totally works :) ..What if I want to copy the Filtered dataset and some specific columns let's say Just Column A & Column C(Skipping column B)along with the header?

Answer (score 0):

Relying on `Areas(2)` is not going to work if the first row under the header is part of the filtered (visible) cells.

```
'at this point, AutoFilter has been applied
'I have no idea what the range is
'or what column you are interested in

with ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
    with .cells.resize(.rows.count-1, 1).offset(1, 0)
        set RngA = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    end with
end with

RngA.copy Destination:=wbA.ActiveSheet.Range("L1")
```

I disagree with your use of ActiveSheet as the parent worksheet references. The source and destination worksheets should be explicitly referenced.